# Which one is the correct answer?

Tags: grammar, clauses

I was doing my homework for CAE when I found this:

> Not ....... well-to-do parents give the support they should, and some
>   parents living in the most

The possible answers are:

a) each

b) all

c) any

d) every

I marked b), but according to the answer sheet the correct one is a).
Please, could anyone make me understand the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @StoneyB points out, the answer sheet is incorrect.
If you remove "***well-to-do***" the correct answer will become easily apparent.

> Not each parents *(ungrammatical)*
>   Not all parents *(grammatical)*
>   Not any parents *(ungrammatical)*
>   Not every parents *(ungrammatical)*

**All** parents would mean each and every one of the parents, so **not all** parents means that there must be some who do not do as **all the other** parents.  So **some** parents (the **not all**) do things differently than the rest.

Comment: You should explain why, along the lines of "not all parents" = "some parents".